# Error: package androidx.databinding does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

Good morning! I know that there's a question pretty similar to this one but I've been a lot of days trying to get a solution and I'm not able to find it.

The thing is that my project is not compiling, I'm running the project with 
**"--debug --stacktrace --debug"** and I'm getting this main error:

```
ListItemAdapter.java:5: error: package androidx.databinding does not exist
```

I say "main" because after this one there are a lot more, like:

```
[ERROR] [system.err] Note: There is no binding for toolbar, reverting to plain layout
[ERROR] [system.err] Note: checking null android.widget.LinearLayout false
```

The thing is that I have a project with more people and one of them migrated it to AndroidX so when I did the pull request I've got an AndroidX project with errors. I think that there's something missing with AndroidX which is that causes this but when I try to migrate to AndroidX it shows this:

[image]

I don't know what more can I do, I'm feeling really stuck... Thank you!

Comment: Do you have databinding enabled in your build.gradle?

Comment: You really gave me a hope but yes, I do. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Do you have `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in your gradle.properties?

Comment: I have build.gradle, gradle-wrapper.properties, settings.gradle, local.properties... But no gradle.properties it's supposed to be on build.gradle, right?

Comment: You should have a gradle.properties file right in the root of your project, outside the `app` folder.

Comment: Yes, I know, in general this file it's on the project but I've seen that this one not. Can this be because it's in gitignore and maybe it's not in the project? Anyway, can I add it manually, right?

Comment: You can and should add it in. You'll want to also have `android.databinding.enableV2=true`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186311/discussion-between-juli15-and-thewanderer).